# input a directory to Java to be proceed

Tags: java, filereader

I have a problem in here. Whenever I entered the directory path that I copy from my computer to input a txt file to my program, it always said that the file is not found. Is there something wrong from my code?

```
System.out.println("insert directory file = ");
FileReader file = null;
try {
    file = new FileReader(input.next());                
    BufferedReader readfile = new BufferedReader(file);              
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while ((text = readfile.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(text);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        readfile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    text = sb.toString();
    //System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println("Data entered");
    System.out.println("Data length = "+text.length()+"\n");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("File not found. Pease insert the proper file directory.\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you include the exception message output by adding e1.printStackTrace() to your catch. This will have information regarding the file name that cannot be found.

Comment: You should provide what path you paste to the console too. I guess there is a copy/paste error

Comment: I write it like this D:\\Home\\data.txt but that wasn't work, is my code already correct?

Comment: I already tried that e1.printStackTrace but that was making my program stop after I enter my pathd irectories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **code segment** run just fine in my laptop. So the problem maybe here :

`file = new FileReader(input.next());`

Did you use your Scanner for other input before read the path? Trying changing it to

```
String path = input.next();
file = new FileReader(path);
```

And print the path when error occur to see what actually was passed to your FileReader.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    System.out.println("File not found. Pease insert the proper file directory.\n");
    System.out.println("Your input path: " + path);
}
```

Here is the working code on my machine :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String path = null;
  try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Input your option = ");
    int option = input.nextInt();
    switch (option) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("insert directory file = ");
        String text = "";
        path = input.next();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader readfile = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
          while ((text = readfile.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(text);
            sb.append("\n");
          }
          readfile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        text = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Data entered");
        System.out.println("Data length = " + text.length() + "\n");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("There is nothing to do.");
        break;
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    System.out.println("File not found. Pease insert the proper file directory.");
    System.out.println("Your input path is : " + path);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how did you enter the path directory? maybe I typed it wrong

Comment: Base on your code, I guess you read it from console by a `Scanner input;` . Is it right?

Comment: and yes, i did use scanner for my menu, case 1 is insert directory I use Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) should I change it ?

Comment: Not necessary to change it. I just type the directory `D:\\Home\\data.txt` when the program ask me to. I think there is a high chance it is a typing error, so I suggest you print the path when error occur

Comment: wait I can't understand you. So basically my code was all okay? and here you ask me to print the path? print like what

Comment: whenever I typed the path dir it always said error input when i tried to my case 2 it won't work . omg how should I fix this

Comment: I said your **code segment**, because i don't see your full code. Ofc, you print the path in the exception handler, see my updated answer.

Comment: int choose;
  String text = null;
 
  boolean flag = true;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(flag == true) {
  System.out.println("Program is running ... \n1. Insert directory\n2. Search pattern\n3. Print text\n4. Out");
  try {
  choose = input.nextInt();
  switch(choose) {
  case 1:
  System.out.println("insert directory file = ");
   FileReader file = null;
String path = input.next();
   
   try {
    file = new FileReader(input.next()); 
file = new FileReader(path); **still not working** please kindly check my code before insert dir to thanks

Comment: Strange, it still work on my laptop, try the working code in my updated answer.

Comment: Also, you should update your full code on your question, so everybody can help.